How to hide or remove Facebook suggested videos at the end or when pausing using Facebook Embed code?
I'm embedding Facebook videos in my Angular project using the Facebook Embed code. However, I'm seeing suggested videos appear at the end of the video or when I pause the video. Here is an example of the embedded video:
here we can see suggestion videos appear
Is there a way to hide or remove these suggested videos?
Here is the current code I'm using to embed the Facebook video:
HTML code
<div #videoContainer id="myIframe"  class="fb-video" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook/videos/1173373513689916/" data-width="500" data-show-text="false"  data-width="500"
data-show-text="false"
data-autoplay="true"
data-allowfullscreen="true"
data-controls="true"
data-show-captions="false"
data-show-post="false"
data-show-social-context="false"
data-show-metadata="false"
data-show-adaptive-playback="false"
data-autoplay-metadata="false"></div>


TS code
import { Component, ElementRef, Input, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
declare var FB: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterOutlet],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.scss'
})
export class AppComponent {
  // @Input() videoUrl: string;
  @ViewChild('videoContainer') videoContainer!: ElementRef;
  private myVideoPlayer: any;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.initializeFB();
  }

  initializeFB() {
    const initParams: any = {
      appId: '317808808064170',
      xfbml: true,
      version: 'v20.0'
    };
    FB.init(initParams);
    FB.Event.subscribe('xfbml.ready', (msg: any) => {
      console.log(msg,'msg')
      if (msg.type === 'video') {
        this.myVideoPlayer = msg.instance;
        this.myVideoPlayer.play();
        this.myVideoPlayer.subscribe('startedPlaying', () => {
          console.log('Video started playing');
        });
        this.myVideoPlayer.subscribe('paused', () => {
          console.log('Video not playing');
          // this.restartVideo()
        });
        this.myVideoPlayer.subscribe('finishedPlaying', () => {
          console.log('Video finished playing',this.myVideoPlayer);
          this.restartVideo()
        });
      }
    });
    FB.XFBML.parse();
  }
  restartVideo() {
    if (this.myVideoPlayer) {
      console.log(this.myVideoPlayer,"video",'vid')
          this.seekTo(0);
      this.myVideoPlayer.seek(0); // Seek to the beginning of the video
      this.myVideoPlayer.play(); // Play the video
    }
  }
  seekTo(seconds: number) {
    if (this.myVideoPlayer) {
      this.myVideoPlayer.seek(seconds);
    }
  }
}


I have tried looking through the Facebook Embed documentation but couldn't find a way to disable the suggested videos. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!
I was expecting to find a way to hide or remove the suggested videos that appear at the end or when the video is paused. I don't want these suggestions to be displayed at all.

I would be surprised if it is possible.

If it were possible, this would most likely be in the documentation. Technically it is not possible to modify the content of an iframe. So it looks like there is nothing you can do about it.
